# OpenCL 2.0 - race in a program with only atomics

Tags: opencl, consistency, memory-model

In the paper "Heterogeneous Race-Free Memory Models", the author states the following:

> "...in OpenCL 2.0 it is possible to write a racey program that is
>   composed entirely of atomics if those atomics do not use scopes
>   correctly..."

How is this possible? Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: I recall from an HSA slideshow (http://www.slideshare.net/hsafoundation/isca-2014-heterogeneous-system-architecture-hsa-architecture-and-algorithms-tutorial) that atomics only work correctly when used within the same type of memory (e.g., workgroup or global). Perhaps that's what the author means by "scopes" in the OpenCL 2.0 paper you're referring to (HSA and OpenCL 2.0 have a lot of similarities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenCL 2.0 specification (page 14)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-2.0.pdf#page=14) states that a program contains a data race if:

> it contains two actions in different work items or host threads where
>
> 1. one action modifies a memory location and the other action reads or modifies the same memory location, and
> 2. at least one of these actions is not atomic, or the corresponding memory scopes are not inclusive, and
> 3. the actions are global actions unordered by the global-happens-before relation or are local actions unordered by the
>      local-happens-before relation.

The second clause implies that even if both actions are atomic, you can still have a data race if the memory scopes are not 'inclusive'. An example of non-inclusive memory scopes is: trying to synchronise between work-items on different devices using `workgroup` scope.

In practice, it may well be that nothing bad will occur if your scopes are non-inclusive. But technically, a program with non-inclusive memory scopes is in violation of the contract defined by the specification, so its behaviour is undefined.